# Show TOC in Beamer under special conditions

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I'm wondering how to display the TOC:

- At beginning of section if there is no subsection
- At beginning of subsection else

Each option can be achieved separately quite easily with the commands

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}
```

or

```
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}
```

respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you basically need a test if the number of subsection within a section is 0. Luckily there is a package to do this: `xcntperchap`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xcntperchap}
\RegisterCounters{section}{subsection}

\newcounter{totalsubsection}
\setcounter{totalsubsection}{0}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \setcounter{totalsubsection}{\ObtainTrackedValueExp[\value{section}]{section}{subsection}}
    \ifnum\value{totalsubsection}=0%
      \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{Outline}
      \tableofcontents[currentsection]
      \end{frame}
    \fi%
}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\title{title}
\author{author}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Section1}
\frame{}

\subsection{Subsection1}
\frame{}

\subsection{Subsection2}
\frame{}

\section{Section2}
\frame{}

\subsection{Subsection1}
\frame{}

\subsection{Subsection2}
\frame{}

\subsection{Subsection3}
\frame{}

\section{Section3}
\frame{}

\end{document}
```

---

As long as no special shading style is used for the subsections, another approach could be to show the section toc after each section, but remove the subsection page if it would immediately follow a section page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcounter{foo}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
      \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{Outline}
      \tableofcontents[currentsection]
      \end{frame}
}
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{   
    \setcounter{foo}{\insertsectionstartpage}
    \addtocounter{foo}{1}
    \ifnum\thefoo=\thepage
    \else
  \begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section1}

\subsection{Subsection1}
\frame{sec 1 sub 1}

\section{Section2}
\frame{sec 2}

\subsection{Subsection1}
\frame{sec 2 sub 1}

\section{Section 3}
\frame{sec 3}

\section{Section4}

\subsection{Subsection1}
\frame{sec 4 sub 1}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow that's great for answering this question that was getting lost!