# Show TOC in Beamer under special conditions, again

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I'm wondering how to display the TOC:

- At beginning of section if and only if (A) there is no subsection or (B) there is a frame in the section *before* the first subsection starts
- At beginning of all subsections

This is very similar to the questino [Show TOC in Beamer under special conditions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172980/show-toc-in-beamer-under-special-conditions) but the answer there doesn't show TOCs under condition 
(B)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcntperchap}
\RegisterCounters{section}{subsection}
\newcounter{totalsubsection}
\setcounter{totalsubsection}{0}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \setcounter{totalsubsection}{\ObtainTrackedValueExp[\value{section}]{section}{subsection}}
    \ifnum\value{totalsubsection}=0%
      \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{Outline}
      \tableofcontents[currentsection]
      \end{frame}
    \fi%
}
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section1}

\subsection{Subsection1}
\frame{first content in section 1 is part of subsection 1 of section 1, therefore section 1 needs no separate introduction}


\section{Section2}
\frame{first content in section 2 comes before first subsection of section 2, therefore section 2 needs introduction at beginning (no one will know that this frame is already part of section 2)}

\subsection{Subsection1}
\frame{It's too late to introduce section 2 with this subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]: